# TypeError: to_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'quoting'

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I take an excel file, load it manipulate the contents in a pandas df and then write it to a csv. using

```
Oracle.to_csv("df.csv",index=False,header=False,quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

but I am getting the following error

```
TypeError: to_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'quoting'
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled pandas but still get the same error

I am not sure how to fix this issue

I am using python 3.5

Comment: @bernie you mean `import pandas as pd`?

Comment: Haha, yes @ abccd! Thank you!

Comment: What does `import pandas as pd; pd.__version__` give you?

Comment: Are you sure the `Oracle` object is a DataFrame? Or is it a Series?

Comment: Please make sure `Oracle` object is a DataFrame (see this question and answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43684096/pandas-to-csv-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument).