# Pandas : to_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

While I am trying to use some of the parameters in dataframe to_csv function, it throws an TypeError, such as `TypeError: to_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'doublequote'

`df.to_csv('transactions.x', header=False, doublequote=False)` 
or 
`df.to_csv('transactions.x', doublequote=False)`

My pandas version is 0.19.2 (Checked with `print(pd.__version__)`)
I am using `Python 3.5`

The following official document is based on 0.19.2. Although, I am having type errors, it is stated that these parameters can be used as an optional. 
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Do you guys have any idea about it?

Thank you.

**SOLUTION**

Thanks for brain storming with all commenters.

After using following the command `df = df.groupby(['Transactions'])['Items'].apply(','.join)`, dataframe becomes series.

In order to cast series to dataframe, this command `df = df.groupby(['Transactions'])['Items'].apply(','.join).to_frame()` should be used instead.

Finally, to export it as a CSV with non-quote style by avoiding escape char, you need to end up with the following command 
`df.to_csv('transactions.x', header=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar=' ')` #or whatever escapechar.

Hopefully, it helps for everyone. 
Thanks

Comment: sorry did you pass `doublequote` or `'doublequote'`? Please post code that reproduces this error

Comment: df.to_csv('transactions.x', header=False, doublequote=False)

Comment: df.to_csv('transactions.x', doublequote=False)

Comment: both of them produce same TypeError issue.

Comment: Sorry this works fine for me, can you try restarting your python kernel to see if this is a transient issue

Comment: Actually, what i think is, 
After I execute the following command, `df = pd.read_sql (......, connection)`
I can call `df.to_csv('transactions.x', header=False, doublequote=False)` successfully because the result is a dataframe object, 
but when I continue to do something with df object such as 
`python df = df.groupby(['Transactions'])['Items'].apply(','.join) `,  the command  `python df.to_csv('transactions.x', header=False, doublequote=False)` becomes invalidated. So, how to cast the apply function to the dataframe in order to use these optional parameters?
Thank you.

Comment: Hmm, I think you don't have a `DataFrame` but rather a `Series` which has no param `doublequote`: see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_csv.html#pandas.Series.to_csv, what does `print(type(df))` show after the groupby? It looks to me this would generate a Series, you can resolve this by doing `df.to_frame().to_csv()` to convert from a `Series` to a `DataFrame`

Comment: Try my answer, the `groupby` is returning a `Series` because you select a single column from the `groupby` object

Answer (score 3):

Would this help:

```
pd.to_csv('test.csv', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

As per your comment, read [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.Series.to_csv.html) on series.

You can use `to_frame` before saving to resolve your issue.

Comment: Same issue, it still throws a same TypeError issue.

Comment: No, all the parameters (quoting, doublequote, etc...) are becoming invalidated since somehow dataframe behaves as a series.

Comment: Thank you but, By typing following command `df = df.groupby(['Transactions'])[['Items']].apply(','.join)` throws the same error, on the other hand if I want to use `df = df.groupby(['Transactions'])[['Items']].apply(','.join).to_frame()` , it does not throw error but output is showing the "Items" instead of real items such as a, b, c, ....
If i use the last option, `df = df.groupby(['Transactions'])['Items'].apply(','.join).to_frame()` , it thows the following `error _csv.Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set`

Answer (score 0):

Your `groupby` call generates a series for which there is no [`doublequote`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_csv.html#pandas.Series.to_csv) param, convert to a DataFrame calling [`to_frame()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html#pandas.Series.to_frame) prior to calling `to_csv`

This:

```
df.groupby(['Transactions'])['Items'].apply(','.join)
```

is grouping your df, but then you select a single column and call `apply` this will return a `Series` hence your error

Comment: I already tried them Thank you but, By typing following command df = df.groupby(['Transactions'])[['Items']].apply(','.join) throws the same error, on the other hand if I want to use df = df.groupby(['Transactions'])[['Items']].apply(','.join).to_f‌​rame() , it does not throw error but output is showing the "Items" instead of real items such as a, b, c, .... If i use the last option, df = df.groupby(['Transactions'])['Items'].apply(','.join).to_fra‌​me() , it thows the following error _csv.Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for brain storming with all commenters.

After using following the command `df = df.groupby(['Transactions'])['Items'].apply(','.join)`, dataframe becomes series.

In order to cast series to dataframe, this command `df = df.groupby(['Transactions'])['Items'].apply(','.join).to_frame()` should be used instead.

Finally, to export it as a CSV with non-quote style by avoiding escape char, you need to end up with the following command  `df.to_csv('transactions.x', header=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar=' ')` #or whatever escapechar.

Hopefully, it helps for everyone. Thanks

Comment: To turn a series to a data frame of a single column, I think you should rather use `to_frame` as suggested in [@zipa's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43684216/1509695), or at least I'm not sure myself why you need that elaborate way that you use here.