# pandas to csv TypeError: get_handle() got an unexpected keyword argument 'errors'

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary, export-to-csv

I had big table which I sliced to many smaller tables based on their dates:

```
dfs={}
for fecha in fechas:
    dfs[fecha]=df[df['date']==fecha].set_index('Hour')
#now I can acess the tables like this:
dfs['2019-06-23'].head()
```

I have done some modifictions to the dfs['2019-06-23'] specific table and now I would like to save it on my computer. I have tried to do this in two ways:

```
#first try:
dfs['2019-06-23'].to_csv('specific/path/file.csv')

#second try:
test=dfs['2019-06-23']
test.to_csv('test.csv')
```

both of them raised this error:

> TypeError: get_handle() got an unexpected keyword argument 'errors'

I don't know why I get this error and haven't find any reason for that. I have saved many files this way but never had that before.

**My goal: to be able to save this dataframe after my modification as csv**

Comment: What is `print (dfs.keys())` ?

Comment: it gives all the dates (e.g :   (['2019-06-22','2019-06-24',...])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end what worked was to use pd.DataFrame and then to export it as following:

```
to_export=pd.DataFrame(dfs['2019-06-23'])

to_export.to_csv('my_table.csv')
```

that suprised me because when I checked the type of the table when I got the error it was dataframe . However, this way it works.

Answer (score 3):

If you are getting this error, there are two things to check:

1. Whether the DataFrame is not actually a Series - see ([Pandas : to_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43684096/pandas-to-csv-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument))
2. Your numpy version. For me, updating to numpy==1.20.1 with pandas==1.2.2 fixed the problem. If you are using Jupyter notebooks, remember to restart the kernel afterwards.