# pandas dataframe to_csv() with get_handle() error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am receiving the following error when trying to convert a pandas dataframe to a csv file:

```
get_handle() got an unexpected keyword argument 'errors'
```

I am using pandas 1.1.0 and I'm using the example code in the docs:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Raphael', 'Donatello'],
                   'mask': ['red', 'purple'],
                   'weapon': ['sai', 'bo staff']})

df.to_csv("C:\\Users\\MyUserName\\Desktop\\example.csv", index = False)
```

Comment: Please try; `df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\example.csv", index = False)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas to csv TypeError: get\_handle() got an unexpected keyword argument 'errors'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64318918/pandas-to-csv-typeerror-get-handle-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-errors)

Comment: @Andreas unfortunately, i'm still getting the same error

Comment: Can you put this line after the first line and paste the output ```print(type(df))```?

Comment: @KaziSohan yep, its a dataframe class `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`

Comment: Can you please also check the numpy version please?

Comment: @KaziSohan I'm using 1.19.2

Comment: I restarted my notebook and things are working now, sorry for this.